# Remove Gaussian weighting of gradient orientation histogram in OpenCV SIFT (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

In the SIFT algorithm, the entries of the gradient orientation histogram are Gaussian weighted, such that orientations farther from the keypoint center contribute less to the histogram. This can be seen in function "ori_hist" in the [source for OpenCV SIFT](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/features2d/src/sift.cpp?rev=5285). I would like to get rid of this weighting such that all gradient orientations contribute equally to the histogram.

Essentially, I would need to change the following line

```
w = exp( -( i*i + j*j ) / exp_denom );
```

to

```
w = 1
```

Is there a Python binding that lets me do this? Or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the source code of OpenCV 2.4.4. Make the necessary changes in the files (C++), build and install it. I once had some problem with Kalman filter(in Python) and to debug, I had added few print statements in the OpenCV source code and rebuilt it. It worked.

Since Python bindings are made from ctypes, if you change the C++ code and build it, it will work in Python.

So if you know C++, and know what you want to change, you can do it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I figured modifying the OpenCV C++ source was what I was going to have to do. It's a simple change so it's not like it's a huge problem. I was just looking for a shortcut. Thanks again!